Convolution with the Inverse FFT of a Box Filter
I read through this post here on an example of filtering using the box function in fourier space. The example makes sense and I was able to follow it and implement it in Julia (I did in space instead of time, so I used x instead of t).
I know that elementwise multiplication in the fourier domain is equivalent to convolution in the spatial domain. As an exercise, I wanted to take the inverse FFT of the box function (and get the sinc function) and then convolve that with the spatial domain signal and show that the filtered result is the same. But I am having some trouble.
Here is an MWE.
using FFTW, Random

# Make a noisy function
begin
    n = 1024
    x = LinRange(1, 10, n)
    Δx = x[2] - x[1]
    k = (2π) / Δx
    kn = k / 2
    dk = k / n
    wbins = collect(-kn:dk:(kn-dk))
    ytruth = @. -(x - 5)^2 + 2
    noise = randn(n)
    ynoise = ytruth .+ noise
    yf = fft(ynoise)
end


begin
    r = 20
    rect = zeros(size(yf))
    rect[1:r+1] .= 1
    rect[n-r+1:n] .= 1
    yfull = ifft(yf .* rect)
end

# Take ifft of the box filter in fourier space
irect = ifft(rect)
# Do convolution
begin
    II = zeros(size(ytruth))
    for i in eachindex(x)
        ff = circshift(irect, i - 1)
        integral_sum = sum(ynoise .* ff)
        II[i] = real.(integral_sum)
    end
    II .*= Δx
end

Below is the result. They do not match. The convolved result is nearly zero. The sinc result from the ifft of rect is also included below and it is very small (maximum value is less than 0.04) which explains why the resulting convolution is so small compared to the fft domain result.
Is there a scaling factor I am missing?
Any hints on how I can achieve the same result as the elementwise multiplication in the fourier domain using the ifft of rect and convolution in the spatial domain?



It's just a scaling factor that you have been inconsistent with, as you suspect. To make the two approaches match, either get rid of the following line or multiply your fft approach by Δx, which is currently missing.
II .*= Δx


Thanks - that does indeed fix everything. I guess I am still confused though why the Δx is not needed. The convolution is an integral so I thought there should be a factor of Δx in there. I'll have to review and convince myself otherwise.

You are correct that it is needed if you want the proper scaling. It's just that it was missing from your fft approach (those functions have no way of knowing what Δx should be, so you have to scale the result by it), so to make the two approaches match, my point was more that you need to either scale both results by Δx or neither, but not only one as you had done.

Yes, I got it now. The FFT was missing the scaling factor of Δx. Thank you
